# Finding value(s) for x where the tangent line of f(x) has a slope of 4.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line, slope

I have this equation $\frac{3}{4}x^4 - 4x^3 + \frac{1}{2}x^2 + 7$

I am trying to find the value(s) for $x$ where the tangent line of $f(x)$ has a slope of 4.

So I take my first derivative which I get $3x^3 - 12x^2 + x$. With this equation do I want to set it to 4 and try factoring my derivative and setting them to 4?

Not really sure if that is the proper set up. Thanks!

EDIT : Edited derivative as I had typed it wrong.

Comment: Few comments: (i) An equation must have an equal sign (that's what the "equa" in "equation" means). You didn't give an equation, you gave an expression. (ii) You never told us who $f(x)$ is; we could guess you mean the expression you gave is the formula for $f(x)$, but I personally am a terrible guesser, so you shouldn't rely on my guessing. (iii) You either got the derivative wrong or you transcribed it wrong; the first term has the wrong exponent. (iv) You are trying to find the solutions to $f'(x) = 4$; *how* you find them... well, that depends on what algebraic tools you know.

Comment: you are correct with your logic.

Comment: Note:  $3 x^3$ (not $3 x^2$)...

Comment: It should be $3x^3 $. Then it is factorized as $ (3x^2+1)*(x-4) = 0$.

Comment: I can tell that I have not been active on MSE - when Arturo Magidin is commenting.

Comment: Ahh sorry I am trying to edit. Yeah $3x^3$

Comment: Writing $3/4x^3$ is prone to error without parentheses.  It appears you mean $(3/4)x^3$ which is strictly the correct reading of what you wrote, but often we would see it when somebody means $3/(4x^3)$.  I would usually stack the fraction, as you had, to get $\frac 34x^3$ or write it as $3x^3/4$.  I find $(3/4)x^3$ harder to read than the other two.

Comment: The LaTeX `\frac` is infinitely better than inline fractions that you wrote. They are hard to parse. I had made the correction, but you specifically went back and rewrite $\frac{3}{4}x^4$ as $3/4x^4$. What did you find bad about the former?

Comment: Ty for the edit @ArturoMagidin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you made a typo in the derivative.

$$
3x^3 - 12 x^2 + x = 4\\
3x^3 - 12 x^2 + x - 4 = 0\\
(3x^3 + x) - (12 x^2 + 4) = 0\\
x(3x^2 + 1) - 4(3x^2 + 1) = 0\\
(x-4)(3x^2+1)=0
$$

so $x=4$ is the only real solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should solve $f'(x) = 4$ for $x$.  You'll find one real solution ($x=4$) and two imaginary solutions.